# How can I expose the layers of a child model from the summary of the parent model in keras?

Tags: python, keras

Right now I have the following model called model1:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)            (None, 101, 101, 1)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_2 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 202, 202, 1)  0           input_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_36 (ZeroPadding2 (None, 256, 256, 1)  0           up_sampling2d_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, 256, 256, 3)  6           zero_padding2d_36[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
u-resnet34 (Model)              (None, 256, 256, 1)  24453178    conv2d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_4 (InputLayer)            (None, 1, 1, 1)      0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
cropping2d_2 (Cropping2D)       (None, 202, 202, 1)  0           u-resnet34[1][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_3 (Lambda)               (None, 1, 1, 1)      0           input_4[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 101, 101, 1)  0           cropping2d_2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_4 (Lambda)               (None, 101, 101, 1)  0           lambda_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_10 (Concatenate)    (None, 101, 101, 2)  0           max_pooling2d_2[0][0]            
                                                                 lambda_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_14 (Conv2D)              (None, 101, 101, 1)  3           concatenate_10[0][0]             
==================================================================================================
Total params: 24,453,187
Trainable params: 24,437,821
Non-trainable params: 15,366
_____________________________________
```

The u-resnet34 layer is another model that has many more layers inside it. I can print the summary of it and I can freeze any layer I want.
When I freeze layers of u-resnet34 and print the summary, I can see that the Trainable params decrease accordingly.

However, even though I'm freezing layers of a model inside model1, the Trainable params of model1 doesn't decrease.

How can I freeze layers of u-resnet34 and make it reflect on the Trainable params of model1?

---

edit:
Bellow is my code

```
# https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models
from segmentation_models import Unet
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Cropping2D, Conv2D

inputs = Input((256, 256, 3))
resnetmodel = Unet(backbone_name='resnet34', encoder_weights='imagenet', input_shape=(256, 256, 3), activation=None)
outputs = resnetmodel(inputs)
outputs = Cropping2D(cropping=((27, 27), (27, 27)) ) (outputs)
outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (outputs)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.summary()
```

That outputs:

```
Total params: 24,453,180
Trainable params: 24,437,814
Non-trainable params: 15,366
```

Then:

```
for layer in resnetmodel.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
resnetmodel.summary()
```

Which outputs:

```
Total params: 24,453,178
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 24,453,178
```

Finnaly this:

```
model.summary()
```

Which outputs this:

```
Total params: 48,890,992
Trainable params: 24,437,814
Non-trainable params: 24,453,178
```

Comment: First you mentioned that when you freeze the layers of u-resnet34, it is reflected in the model summary. Then you mentioned it is not reflected. Which one is correct? Or am I missing something?

Comment: There are two summaries. One for the u-resnet34 model and another for the model1, which has u-resnet34 inside.

Comment: Could add the codes you use to freeze layer(s) in both cases?

Comment: The first and last summary both belong to the `model`, but the total number of parameters are different in them. How is it like that?

Comment: I was wondering that myself, but I think you can reproduce the problem there as well.

Comment: I think I got it, you have to compile it again in order to correct the summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see with `ResNet50` as an example.

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50

res = ResNet50()
res.summary()
#....
#Total params: 25,636,712
#Trainable params: 25,583,592
#Non-trainable params: 53,120
```

Resnet model has a lot of parameters to train.

Let's put this as a layer of a model.

```
x = Input((224,224,3))
y = res(x)
y = Dense(10)(y)
model = Model(x, y)
model.summary()
#.....
#Total params: 25,646,722
#Trainable params: 25,593,602
#Non-trainable params: 53,120
```

Freeze the layers of resnet.

```
for layer in res.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
res.summary()
# ....
#Total params: 25,636,712
#Trainable params: 0
#Non-trainable params: 25,636,712
```

This reflects to the model that use resnet as well.

```
model.summary()
#.....
#Total params: 25,646,722
#Trainable params: 10,010
#Non-trainable params: 25,636,712
```

So, freezing layers of inner models should reflect to the outer model.

**EDIT**

If you compile the model before freezing your model, you need to compile it again.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Your code worked  here, but my code still doesn't. I posted my code in the question, so you can understand it better.

Comment: The single important difference between my code and yours is the compile method. After you compile your model, it stops working.
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

Comment: I got it, thanks to your code. You need to compile it again in order to update the summary. I'm marking your answer as correct, but please mention that later.